# AngularJS BootstrapUI DatePicker global options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I was putting this code into every page that used one or more datepickers:

```
$scope.open = function ($event, datepicker) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    $event.stopPropagation();
    $scope.opened[datepicker] = true;
};
$scope.dateOptions = {
    startingDay: 1,
    showWeeks: false
};
```

I'm trying to move this all into a global configuration, which I've got partially working with this:

```
function config(datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
    datepickerConfig.startingDay = 1;
    datepickerConfig.showWeeks = false;
}
```

Is it possible to move the `.open` code into the global configuration?

Comment: You are using jQuery datepicker right? 

Whether you have to keep using it consider to wrap this code into an angular directive , so you can encapsulate these events handler inside that - https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive. Otherwise I suggest you to go for angular-strap-datepicker instead of recreate it with jQuery - http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepickers.

Comment: I'm using angularUI - https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/.